# PHP call two functions but save variable from first one?

Tags: php, templates, scope

i am trying to set a title with the function below and then call another function so i can render the view but after I cannot see the title. here is my code:

snippet from another file:

```
$indexPage = new View();
$indexPage->setPageTitle('This is the title');
$indexPage->render('index');
```

This is my view class:

```
class View {

    private $title;

    public function render($file) {
        require '/view/header.php';
        require '/view/'.$file.'.php';
        require '/view/footer.php';
    }

    public function setPageTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

}
```

then I would access it on my page:

index.php:

```
<?php echo $this->title ?>
```

but it does not show.

Comment: It should work as per your case here. For debugging purpose, switch on error reporting and see if there are any errors

Comment: @Thamilan nevermind this is working now thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will not show. If you created View object in `index.php` as mentioned in code snipet then you call `<?php echo $indexPage->title ?>` Otherwise when you rendered view template you have to pass data like most MVC does.

Note: make title variable public if you want to access it directly otherwise write another public function and return the private member.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<?php echo $indexPage->title ?>` and changing `private $title;` to `public $title;`.

Private variables cannot be accessed outside of the class they're in.